# TypeScript, Type '(status: string) => { text: string; onClick: () => void; }[]' is not assignable to type '{ text: string; onClick: () => void; }[]'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to understand what this TypeScript error is telling me and how to resolve it.

```
Type '(status: string) => { text: string; onClick: () => void; }[] | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ text: string; onClick: () => void; }[]'
```

I have a header component which accepts an array of objects.

I can pass the array in as follows with no issues.

```
        menuItems={[
          { text: 'Save', onClick: () => console.log('test1') },
          {
            text: 'Submit Referral Request',
            onClick: () => console.log('test2'),
          },
        ]}
      />
```

Now what I want to do is extract the array and replace it with a function call that will build an array.

```
  function renderActionMenuItems(status: string) {
    if (status === 'new') {
      return new Array(
        { text: 'Save', onClick: () => console.log('test1') },
        {
          text: 'Submit Referral Request',
          onClick: () => console.log('test2'),
        }
      )
    }
  }


      <ActionBar
        menuItems={renderActionMenuItems}
      />
```

However the above code gives me an error when running the app.
`ActionBar.tsx:83  Uncaught TypeError: t2.map is not a function`

and the following error in my IDE

```
Type '(status: string) => { text: string; onClick: () => void; }[] | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ text: string; onClick: () => void; }[]'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(93, 5): The expected type comes from property 'menuItems' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HeaderProps'
```

Comment: does ActionBar allow for the menuItems prop to be passed in as a function? On top of @Daniel Gimenez's answer you may need to change this to actually calling the function (with whatever status) to properly pass the type requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you need to return an empty array if status is not "new":

```
function renderActionMenuItems(status: string) {
  if (status === 'new') {
    return new Array(
      { text: 'Save', onClick: () => console.log('test1') },
      {
        text: 'Submit Referral Request',
        onClick: () => console.log('test2'),
      }
    )
  }
  return []; // <-- Would have returned undefined without explicitly returning.
}
```

Consider typing your array elements and having a return type defined for the function.  Explicitly defining return types will help you avoid issues like this in the future.

```
interface MenuType { 
 text: string;
 onClick: () => void;
}

/** This would've shown an error in the IDE: */
function renderActionMenuItems(status: string): MenuType[] { // <-- Return type
  /* ... */
}
```